# In a CSS transform, how to prevent shifting of scaled up element when scaling down

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to use css to scale an element up on mouse hover and scaled it down again when the mouse leaves the element. The upper left edge should stay the same throughout all scaling.

The following code does almost what I want except that when I leave the mouse the element is shifted to the left before it is scaled down. I want the scaling down to start at the end position after the scaling up.

How can I accomplish this?

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  transition: transform 2s;
}  
#test:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that is happening is that you declare `transform-origin` on the first time when you hover the element.

Solution:
Move `transform-origin: left top;` from `#test:hover` to `#test`.

Comment: No problems. I edited your question code - added snippet to demonstrate the issue. Enjoy code!

Comment: Nice, thanks again. Indeed I'm enjoying that I can continue to code my website after this little hang-up :-)